# How do I make casting to BasicDBList?

Tags: java, mongodb, arraylist, casting

I have an `ArrayList` (`json.get("pecas")`) in which needs to be transformed into `BasicDBList`, I tried to turn on `BasicDBObject` before. How do I do that?

```
BasicDBList pecas = ((BasicDBList) json.get("pecas"));
```

Error

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to com.mongodb.BasicDBList
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use ArrayList's .addAll() [see here for details](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#addAll(java.util.Collection))

Here is an example of converting an ArrayList to a BasicDBList. I just used String since I don't know what type your ArrayList is. Make changes accordingly.

```
    BasicDBList dblist = new BasicDBList();
    // create arraylist to use
    ArrayList<String> alist = new ArrayList<String>();
    alist.add("blip");
    alist.add("bloop");
    alist.add("blap");

    dblist.addAll(alist); 

    System.out.println(dblist);
}
```